# Can we skip stemming for some words in text analysis?

Tags: r, text-mining

I am doing text analysis , I know before entering text to analysis , we need to do some pre-processing like return the word to its roots.

However, some words have different meaning like "meet" and "meeting" or "product" and "production" so if I return the word to its roots, the meaning would go.

Is there pro and cons for stemming? Can I skip stemming for certain words?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither stemmatization nor lemmatization can guarantee you the correct "meaning" of a word, these operations are not semantic analysis.

Comment: @ttnphns then why I should stem/lemmatize before analysis?

Comment: Obviously, to bring various grammatical versions of a word to a single standard, so that, for example, "cat" and "cats" count as same word, or "beautiful" and "beautifully" as same word. This is grammatical, not semantic operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preprocess tokens, but don't want to use stemming, [lemmatization](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html) is an alternative that collapses less words together.

For example in Python you can do this using `nltk` (you can also do it in R according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28214148/how-to-perform-lemmatization-in-r/47173854#47173854))

```
>>> stemmer = nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()
>>> stemmer.stem('production')
'product'
```

But using Wordnet lemmatizer

```
>>> lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> lemmatizer.lemmatize('production')
'production'
```